# Do an action when user closes browser while on PayPal checkout page

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have a website that uses PayPal as the payment gateway.

When the user fills up a form and clicks on Pay button, it redirects to PayPal checkout page. What happens is, I perform a code to send the form data to the database and then it redirects to PayPal.

Now, when the user is in the PayPal screen, there is 2 ways for them to not make a payment.

1st - To click on Cancel and return to website

2nd - Click the X on browser

What I need to do is to make sure that if the user did not make a payment, it would then delete the record which was sent to the database.

So this is what I tried:

I added the following code to the standard PayPal html hidden fields

`<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value = "https://www.mydomain.com.sg/pagename?orderstatus=cancel">`

```
if($orderstatus == 'cancel') {
        $sql3 = "DELETE from table order by CustomerID desc 
limit 1";
    }
```

I also added the above sql statement so when that page attribute cancel is reached, it will auto delete the latest record.

Now, this works when user clicks on cancel and return to website (on paypal) which is good.

However, this does not work when the user clicks the close (X) browser button.

So my question is, how do I perform the above code when someone clicks the browser close on PayPal?

Answer (score 2):

If the browser is displaying Paypal's page then you have no control there. You can't modify the scripts or HTML so there's little you can do.

I had a similar problem once. My solution was to timestamp the order at creation and run a scheduled job once a hour that, amongst other things,  cancelled all the orders that hadn't completed after a few hours.

Comment: You mean you had to manually check the orders to see if it was paid? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If by 'manually' you mean that someone looked at all the orders - no. we had a CRON job that ran various tasks on the system. One of those tasks was to cancel (we didn't delete them) any orders that weren't completed within a few hours (I think we chose 12 hours, but there was some debate about much shorter periods)